# calculator button images for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Tkinter and writing a calculator application in python. I have been unable to find calculator button images for things like x^2, the nth root of x and so on. I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a collection of these images.

Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) may be helpful.  Basically, googling whatever image you need, followed by the word "image" should work.  ex. `"x-squared image"`

Comment: Thank you. Of course, you came up with the one method I didn't try to find images.